# Javascript not working when accessing from remote computer

Tags: javascript, xampp

I accessed my client page using this link

```
http://XX.XX.XX.XX/project/client.php
```

.It has few lines of javascript and html but its not working at all . But when i access my client page using this link

```
http://localhost/project/client.php
```

, it works. I know something i should change in javascript code but i dont know what . So please tell me . Here is my client code :

```
<html>
<head>


<style>

#chatlog {width:440px; height:200px; border:1px solid;overflow:auto;}
  #userslog {width:440px; height:200px; border:1px solid;overflow:auto;}
#msg {width:330px; height:100px;}
</style>

<script>



function initialize(){
  var host = "ws://localhost:12345/project/server3z.php";
  try{
    socket = new WebSocket(host);
    chatlog('WebSocket - status '+socket.readyState);
    socket.onopen    = function(event){chatlog("WebSocket status "+this.readyState); };
    socket.onmessage = function(event){ chatlog(event.data); };
    socket.onclose   = function(){ chatlog("WebSocket  status "+this.readyState); };
socket.onerror    = function(event){chatlog("Error :"+event.data); };
  }
  catch(err){ chatlog(err); }

}

function send()
{
  var chat;

  chat= document.getElementById("msg").value;
  if(!chat){ alert("Message can not be empty"); return; }

  try{ socket.send(chat); chatlog('Sent: '+chat); } catch(err){ log(err); }
  document.getElementById("msg").value = "";
}
function quit(){
  chatlog("closed!");
  socket.close();
  chatlog("WebSocket  status "+socket.readyState);

}



function chatlog(msg)
{
var match=msg.match(/10101010101010/g);
if(match)
{
var msg=msg.split("10101010101010");
document.getElementById("userslog").innerHTML+="<br>"+msg[0];
}
else
{
document.getElementById("chatlog").innerHTML+="<br>"+msg;
}
}

function onkey(event){ if(event.keyCode==13){ send(); } }

</script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<center>
<div id="chatlog"></div>
<input id="msg" type="textbox" onkeypress="onkey(event)"/>
<button onclick="send()">Send</button>
<button onclick="quit()">Stop</button>
<div id="userslog"></div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you mean by not working??? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using WebSocket are you sure that your browser in the other PC it's supports HTML5 and WebsoCKET?

WebSocket was introduced early

Comment: I mean why downvote? The title said: "accessing from remote computer"... so the browser on that remote pc might not support WebSocket.

Comment: Did you solve? I'm not asking you for a vote up. I'm just disappointed for the vote down. So.. at least let me know if was for this reason :-)

Comment: yes you guessed right. i was using that browswer which does not support websocket

Answer (score 6):

Don't hard-code the host to `localhost`, use `location.hostname` instead:

```
var host = "ws://" + location.hostname + ":12345/project/server3z.php";
```

Comment: hey , what is location.hostname ? can you give example please ?

Comment: @AnubhavJhalani `location.hostname` is the part of the current URL after the scheme, and before the first slash, excluding the port. Example: `www.google.com`, `stackoverflow.com`. In your case, when you access the page through `http://localhost:80/`, `location.hostname` will be "localhost" - no problem. **However**, when you visit the page through `http://192.168.1.0/`, your current method will fail (because you've hardcoded `http://localhost:12345`). Your code will start to work again if you use `location.hostname`.

Comment: so u want to say that i should use var host = "ws://192.168.1.0:12345/project/server3z.php"   ?? am i right ?

Comment: @AnubhavJhalani No, not at all. I say that you should **not** put the literal *local* URL in the string, but use the `location.hostname` property, as shown in my answer. If you use `host = "ws://192.168.1.0:12345/`, you'll see that your code breaks when you move to a different network.

Comment: ohk i got it . thank you very much . i will check it and will back to you later :)

Comment: one more thing i want to ask . in my server code localhost is written to start the server. should i change it too ?? something about it, is written in comments but i did not understand.Please clarify it 

[code]
// start the server
$Server = new PHPWebSocket();

// for other computers to connect, you will probably need to change this to your LAN IP or external IP,
// alternatively use: gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
$Server->wsStartServer('localhost', 12345);[/code]

Answer (score 0):

this line i sthe problem `var host = "ws://localhost:12345/project/server3z.php";`
localhost by default means your local machine. so when you access it from you local machine it maps to the correct machine but when you access it from a remote server it just searches that server because now the localhost is changed

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have a hardcoded reference to a url on your local host:

```
var host = "ws://localhost:12345/project/server3z.php";
```

If you want to access it from another computer, you'll need to replace that with a domain or ip address that the remote client can resolve.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answer !! :)

madthew was right . I was using IEwhich does not support websocket. It is working in my mozila now.